# Change app name in App Store to the name of another app that it is now removed

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have app called "X-". It's already approved in the app store. I had't used "X" because of another app with the same name. Now this other app with the name "X" is removed from app store. Can I rename my app from "X-" to "X"?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you cannot use a name again if an app already exists with that name in the given language, regardless of the status of that app.

iTunes Connect will show an error if you try this anyways:

> The app name you entered is already being used. If you have trademark rights to this name and would like it released for your use, submit a claim.